# extract netcdf pr based on one location for a given lat and long

Tags: matlab, netcdf, coordinate

I am working with MATLAB to extract pr variable for the whole time period from a netcdf file for a specific lat and long coordinates.

My location has lat=36 and long=9.15. The netcdf file has a Latitude matrix of 453 X 453 and a Longitude matrix of 453 X 453.

Variables:

```
lon              
       Size:       453x453
       Dimensions: x,y
       Datatype:   double
       Attributes:
                   standard_name = 'longitude'
                   long_name     = 'longitude'
                   units         = 'degrees_east'
lat              
       Size:       453x453
       Dimensions: x,y
       Datatype:   double
       Attributes:
                   standard_name = 'latitude'
                   long_name     = 'latitude'
                   units         = 'degrees_north'
time             
       Size:       1826x1
       Dimensions: time
       Datatype:   double
       Attributes:
                   standard_name = 'time'
                   units         = 'days since 1949-12-01'
                   calendar      = 'gregorian'
                   bounds        = 'time_bnds'
                   axis          = 'T'
                   long_name     = 'time'
pr               
       Size:       453x453x1826
       Dimensions: x,y,time
       Datatype:   single
       Attributes:
                   _FillValue    = 1.000000020040877e+20
                   grid_mapping  = 'Lambert_Conformal'
                   standard_name = 'precipitation_flux'
                   long_name     = 'precipitation'
                   units         = 'kg m-2 s-1'
                   cell_methods  = 'time: mean'
                   coordinates   = 'lat lon'
```

Now... I would like to find the closest point in the Latitude and longitude matrix of the netcdf file to my actual lat and long coordinates.

I did that using:

```
d = (mylat-Latnetcdf).^2+(mylong-Longnetcdf).^2; 
[~, ind] = min(d(:)); 
resultlat = lat(ind); %// use that index to obtain the result
resultlong = long(ind);
```

...and this returns the ind=50049.

...then when I try to extract the pr variable from file using:

```
ncread(netcdfname,'pr', [50049,50049, 1], [1 1 inf]);
```

...it returns error:

```
Error using netcdflib
The NetCDF library encountered an error during execution of 'getVarsFloat' function - 'Index exceeds dimension
bound (NC_EINVALCOORDS)'.

Error in netcdf.getVar (line 136)
    data = netcdflib(funcstr,ncid,varid,varargin{:});

Error in internal.matlab.imagesci.nc/read (line 635)
                data  = netcdf.getVar(gid, varid, ...

Error in ncread (line 58)
vardata = ncObj.read(varName, varargin{:});
```

Comment: I don't know matlab, use python, but you need to calculate the ind for the lat and long separately. They may or may not have different indexes. Your ncread index should look like [lon_ind,lat_ind, 1]. HTH.

Answer (score 0):

from the command line in bash:

```
cdo remapnn,lon=9.15/lat=36 input.nc output.nc
```

Comment: I think someone doesn't like CDO... these 1-line answers are all getting marked down ;-)  So Laykeh, does this help you?

Comment: I did downvote some of your answers (and no, I do like CDO... :-)); IMHO questions targeting a specific language shouldn't be answered with *"you can do this easily in another language / with another tool"*. If I have a problem that I would like to solve in Python, I want to see a solution with Python, not NCO/CDO/NCL/R/Fortran/IDL/Matlab/.... (In addition, see e.g. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290046/if-the-question-is-specifically-about-a-certain-language-is-an-answer-in-anothe)

Comment: But sometimes people don't know of the existence of CDO/NCO to complete a task and I have seen people comment that they have switched to a CDO/NCO based solution as a result.  Often it is the task that is the key and people only ask the question based on a certain language because that is what they are familiar with and thus were attempting to use to solve that task.  Also sometimes other users are looking to solve that particular task but are not wedded to a particular language...  but there we go... I will delete it when it hits -3 to at least get a peer pressure badge ;-)

Comment: ps: are you the KNMI Bart that I know by the way? :-D

Comment: That's true, but (again, in my opinion) perhaps the CDO onliner suggestion is better of as a comment? p.s. there are two Bart's at the KNMI, so 50% chance, although it is more likely that you know the other one since I just started there... :-)

Comment: Typing code in a comment is a mess as you can't format it.  And this is an answer, even if not one to everyone's taste, I suppose that is what the voting system is for at the end of the day.  Okay well say hi to the other Bart when you see him then... ;-)